# How to remove make error during uboot build in altera arria 10?

Tags: linux, tar

I am building Linux OS for our custom board which uses Altera Arria 10 SoC.
My Linux Version is 14.04 and by taking reference from below link, I am designing Uboot
https://www.intel.cn/content/www/cn/zh/programmable/documentation/drn1501734984318.html#cpq1511753813487
I have used Quartus Prime Pro Edition(17.1) and SOC EDS 17.1 tool for generating uboot_w_dtb-mkpimage.bin image for sd card boot on custom board.

In the last step of make :
No rule to make target `/host_tools/altera/bootloaders/u-boot/uboot-socfpga.tar.gz', needed by`uboot-socfpga/.untar'.  Stop.
Error is encountered.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5IeN.png)

How to remove this error and generate uboot image.

Thanks and Regards,
Priya.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt those tools will expect a new folder to be created in the root directory `/`, as shown in your image (`/host_tools/altera/...`).

In the instructions that you linked, one code snippet shows something like `$SOCEDS_DEST_ROOT/host_tools/python/bin/`.

So there's probably guidance around what to set SOCEDS_DEST_ROOT to, and you may need to perform additional build steps first before `make` will work in the directory that you're using. From the looks of it, that particular variable is set like:

> Set the SOCEDS_DEST_ROOT and the DS5_ROOT according to the location of the SoC FPGA EDS and Arm® DS-5® Intel® SoC FPGA Edition tools, respectively.

In general, those instructions look a little gross. I'd recommend following them, carefully, from the beginning.